# Atom's JavaScript autocompletion in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, autocomplete, atom-editor

Today, I've been trying to get autocompletion on **Atom** through `autocomplete+` and `ternjs` packages. However, I don't know how to get **autocompletion for external libraries** like `lodash.js`. I've found a [`lodash-autocomplete`](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-lodash) package that works on `.js` files.

Is there a workaround to get it working in `.ts` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered in the official [Atom FAQ](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-do-i-make-atom-recognize-a-file-with-extension-x-as-language-y/26539):

> Atom includes a feature called "custom file types" which you can use by adding some entries into your `config.cson` that look like this:
>
> ```
> core:  
>   customFileTypes:  
>     'source.js': [  
>       'ts'  
>     ]
> ```

Take note that this might lead to some undesired side-effects, e.g. duplicate snippets/autocompletions. As a long-term fix, consider requesting this feature from the author of the package.

Comment: PS: I submitted a [pull-request](https://github.com/HiDeoo/autocomplete-lodash/pull/4), upvoting might speed up the process of merging it